# PHP header won't redirect to home.php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubI-UjqHU18&index=35&list=PLA7F9875BD031DC16) on a website I am designing myself. I have run into two major problems:

The first being that when the code comes to the `header("location: home.php");` command the script erases the entire screen instead and echo's pass onto the blank screen. Meaning the login credentials have passed. For some reason the header() function is not redirecting to the home.php page. My site is hosted on bluehost.com.

My second problem is that the while loop I commented out will not allow the page to load which is another problem that has stumped me.

code:

```
    <header id="header">
    <?php 
            include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php" );
            session_start();
            if(isset($_POST['login'])){                 
                $user_login = strip_tags(@$_POST['user_login']);
                $password_login = strip_tags(@$_POST['login_password']);

                $password_login = md5($password_login);

                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$user_login' AND password='$password_login' LIMIT 1");
                $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                if($userCount == 1){
                    /*while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                        $id = row["id"];
                    }*/
                    echo("pass");
                    $_SESSION['user_login'] = $user_login;
                    header("location: home.php");
                    exit();
                }else {
                    echo("invalid username/password");
                    exit();
                }
            }
    ?>
        <div id="top-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <ul id="top-info">
                            <li>Phone: 703-518-4325</li>
                            <li>Email: <a href="mailto:info@urbanare.com">info@urbanare.com</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav pull-right" id="top-buttons" style="line-height:10px !important;">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Log in<strong class="caret"></strong></a></a>
                                <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px;">
                                    <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                        email: <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user_login" size="30" />
                                        password: <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="login_password" size="30" />
                                        <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" />
                                        <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>
                                        <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="login" value="Sign In" />
                                    </form>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="divider"></li>

                            <li><a href="../register"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Register</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sticky-wrapper"><div id="nav-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index.html" class="nav-logo"><img src="./files/logo_transparent.png" alt="UrbanaRE Logo"></a>

                        <!-- BEGIN SEARCH -->
                        <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
                            <form>
                                <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Search..." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
                                <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
                                <i class="fa fa-search sb-icon-search"></i>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END SEARCH -->

                        <!-- BEGIN MAIN MENU -->
                        <nav class="navbar">
                            <button id="nav-mobile-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Home<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index.html">Home Search</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index-slider.html">Home Slider</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index-grid.html">Home Grid</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index-map.html">Home Map</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Properties<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/properties-detail.html">Properties Detail</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/properties-list.html">Properties List</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/properties-grid.html">Properties Grid</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/properties-grid2.html">Properties Grid 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown" href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Pages<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="./filse/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html">Agency</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/agency-detail.html">Agency Detail</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/agency-listing.html">Agency Listing</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html">Agent</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/agent-detail.html">Agent Detail</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/agent-listing.html">Agent Listing</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/pricing-tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/login.html">Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/register.html">Register</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/404.html">404</a></li>

                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html"> Separated link </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Blog<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-detail.html">Blog Detail</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-listing1.html">Blog Listing 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-listing2.html">Blog Listing 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-listing3.html">Blog Listing 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-listing4.html">Blog Listing 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </nav>
                        <!-- END MAIN MENU -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>
    </header>
    <!-- END HEADER -->
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues here:

1. You should not use `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated and dangerous. Use `mysqli_` functions instead.
2. You should not output anything before the `header()` function. Comment out the `echo $pass` and `<header id="header">`
3. You are missing a `$` in this line: `$id = row["id"];`. It should be `$id = $row["id"];`
4. Your `header` function is incorrect. The location must at least have a slash at the beginning: `header("Location: /home.php");`

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you're doing the following:

```
echo("pass");
```

And you also have:

```
<header id="header">
```

Before you're redirecting the user. That causes the *"Headers Already Sent"* error. Preventing your `header()` call from being run, since... your headers have already been sent.

Remove that line and it should work.

---

Notes

You would've seen the error if you turned error reporting on. You can turn it on by putting the following at the top of your PHP script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I removed the echo("pass") and added the error log this is what I got

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/urbanas8/public_html/register/index.php:19299) in /home/urbanas8/public_html/register/inc/header.inc.php on line 7 Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/urbanas8/public_html/register/index.php:19299) in /home/urbanas8/public_html/register/inc/header.inc.php on line 7

Comment: So what is on line `19299` in your `/home/urbanas8/public_html/register/index.php` file.

Comment: <?php include("./inc/header.inc.php"); ?>

Comment: line 7 is session_start();

Comment: `session_start();` must be the absolute first line on the page. Don't include or echo or do anything before running that function

Comment: now I get 
"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/urbanas8/public_html/register/index.php:19299) in /home/urbanas8/public_html/register/inc/header.inc.php on line 24"

Comment: line 24 is "header("location: home.php");"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you start out by outputting content to the clients' browser (the `<header id="header">` and the `echo $pass`).

I bet if you checked your logs you would find a statement in there along the lines "Cannot send headers; headers already sent in ...". As soon as any output is done the headers are transmitted as well and you can't add new ones.

The header is called `Location` btw, not `location`.

From [RFC 2616 - "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1", Section 4.2, "Message Headers"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the
>   field value. **Field names are case-insensitive**.

As for your loop it's `$row['id']`, not `row['id']`

Comment: `Field names are case-insensitive` then `Location` and `location` should be the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending a php header, you can't have outputted anything up to that point.  At this point, you already have outputted

```
<header id="header">
```

which means that when you output headers, it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

the while loop problem is you are missing $ sign before row

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                        $id = row["id"];
                    }
```

change  it to

```
$id = ---->$row["id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `echo("pass");` form if statement. and you missed $ sign on while loop `row["id"]`;

Comment: Answer needs to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

What about Javascript function?

```
if($userCount == 1){
         echo("pass");
         $_SESSION['user_login'] = $user_login;
         header("location: home.php");
         echo "<script>js:function(){ window.location("url to your home.php"); }</script>";
         exit();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have any output before the header() function is called either PHP or HTML like  in your code.

Reference PHP Manual: [header function PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.